# Nodejs - Path Traverse Up and Down Directory

Tags: node.js, path

I am trying to using the `path` module to traverse up from my current location file location to another folder where there is a file that I am trying to load. Despite efforts to use `path.join()` with the first value being the current file location `__dirname` and the second using directory changes, `../../config/*file*` I'm seeing any file traversing. I see the appending of the second condition in the method and not every level I added `../`. Is there a better way to traverse the directory and does anyone know what might be wrong with my current setup?

**Directory Layout**

```
/root
  /app
    /controllers
      /app
        /activity-feed (Current Directory)
          feed.js (Route logic)
  /config
    pk-*unique-id*.pem (File trying to be loaded)
```

`/app` is one the same layer as `/config`, which are the first folders down from the root of the project

**Here is my attempt at traversing up and then down to this file:**

```
var cfPK = path.join(__dirname + "../../../config/pk-*unique-id*.pem");
```

**This is the error:**

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/my-app/app/controllers/app/activity-feed../config/pk-*unique-id*.pem'
```

Comment: If you're trying to hide your PEM ID, I think you left it in one of your code snippets

Comment: @timothyclifford it isn't active, but good call. Edited and suggested edit to an answer below.

Comment: Yep approved and +1 :) Did my answer solve your issue or still having problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `path.join` and concatenating the paths rather than joining:

```
var cfPK = path.join(__dirname + "../../../config/pk-*unique-id*.pem");
```

Which should instead be:

```
var cfPK = path.join(__dirname, "../../../config/pk-*unique-id*.pem");
```

> Take note of the comma instead of +

Answer (score 0):

You can get the present working dir using

> process.env.PWD

and then move up using

> path.join(process.env.PWD, /..);